# Intersection of $max(R)$ with a closed subset in $Spec(R)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $E$ be a nonvoid closed subset of $Spec(R)$. If $U$ is an open subset of $Spec(R)$ with $E∩Max(R)⊆U$, where $Max(R)$ is the set of maximal ideals of $R$, is it necessarily true that $E⊆U$?
I think that we must use the topology induced by the varieties $V(A)$ when $A$ are the ideals of $R$.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is true. If there were and ideal $\mathfrak{a} \in E\cap U^c$ then there would be a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \supseteq  \mathfrak{a}$. Since both $E$ and $U^c$ are closed,  $\mathfrak{m}\in E\cap U^c$ contrary to assumption.